# How to access Exception object in a jsp page placed at 'META-INF/resources' folder of jar?

Tags: java, jsp, jar

I want to place an *error.jsp* page in **META-INF/resources** folder of a JAR, so that my web-applications may get redirected to this common error page.
Though, I am able to redirect the applications to this *error.jsp* page, but the page can't access the implicit `exception` object, so as to print stack-trace.
While, the `exception` implicit object is `null` in this page.
I've already added the `<%@ page isErrorPage="true"%>` tag in error.jsp.

Is there any other way around to access the Exception object from this jsp page ?

Comment: How are you doing the redirect? Are you using web.xml errpage tags or redirecting from a filter?

Comment: I'm redirecting from a filter defined in the same jar.

Comment: If you redirect rather than forward you are creating a new request therefore the request attributes are no longer there to access

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Implicit exception object** will be available if it is automatically called by JSP itself using below code somewhere in a jsp or setting in web.xml for error page.

```
<%@page errorPage=”relativeURL/path of the error page” %>
```

**In case of manual redirection implicit exception object will not be available because it's just like a normal jsp page.**

> A JSP page specifies the error page with the `page` directive and `errorPage` attribute. When an unhanded exception occurs, any un-flushed output in the output stream is discarded and the error page is immediately executed.
>
> The error page indicates that it is an error page with the `page` directive and `isErrorPage` attribute. This makes the un-handled exception available in a variable called `exception`.

**Don't** redirect/forward to error page manually if you need implicit exception object.

---

As you are doing manual redirection to the **error.jsp** page. You have do set the exception somewhere as the request attribute.

Before redirecting to the **error.jsp** page just set an attribute in the request

```
request.setAttribute("exception",exception);  // You have to set it manually
```

and retrieve back in the **error.jsp** page.

```
request.getAttribute("exception");
```

---

Note: You can try with **JSTL** as well using [c:set](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_core_set_tag.htm).

Comment: Thanks @Braj!  
Though, `request.getAttribute(...)` didn't work for me. But, I got it done by `session.getAttribute(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a forward instead of a redirect:

```
request.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("error.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

Comment: The redirect is performed by a third-party API, so I can't change its flow. However, isn't there any way to pass the same `exception` object to the redirected request ?

Comment: If you don't have control over the rediecting class I'm not sure how you could do this.

Comment: @SiKelly If error page is manually called then implicitly exception object will not be available because it's just like a normal jsp page. Implicit exception object works if error page is called by JSP engine itself via errorPage attribute or settings in web.xml for error pages.